# UITabBar "more" does not respect background color

Tags: swiftui

[image: View]

I have tried `.listRowBackground(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Background View@*/Color.black/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)` and a few other methods but I am at a loss. here is the swift file:

```
          ContactUsView()
          .tabItem {
              Label("Contact Us", systemImage: "ellipsis.bubble")
              .font(Font.title.weight(.ultraLight))

          }
          .tag("Eight")
      
    }
    .accentColor(.white)
    .tint(.white)
    .onAppear {
      UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation") // Forcing the rotation to portrait
      AppDelegate.orientationLock = .portrait // And making sure it stays that way
  }.onDisappear {
      AppDelegate.orientationLock = .all // Unlocking the rotation when leaving the view
  }
    .onAppear {
                let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
                appearance.backgroundEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterial)
                appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.black.opacity(1.0))
                
                // Use this appearance when scrolling behind the TabView:
                UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
                // Use this appearance when scrolled all the way up:
                UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
}
}
```

I'm assuming this might be a 16 beta issue that I should submit to feedback?

Comment: Also '.background(Color.purple)' does not modify either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        .preferredColorScheme(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.dark/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
```

adding this will at least get you black